# Why aren't recently visited files at the front of the list for `ido-switch-buffer`?

Tags: ido, recentf

I don't understand why, no matter what, *scratch*, *Messages*, *Compile-Log* etc are always the buffers that show up first.

I use now this little function

```
(defun ido-recentf-open ()
  "Use `ido-completing-read' to \\[find-file] a recent file"
  (interactive)
  (if (find-file (ido-completing-read "Find recent file: " recentf-list))
      (message "Opening file...")
    (message "Aborting")))
```

But isn't this how `ido-switch-buffer` is supposed to work in the first place?

Comment: Please pose a separate question to ask how to get the absolute file name for a buffer to be displayed. One question per question, please. Thx.

Comment: The question isn't too clear. Are you asking about the behavior of `ido-switch-buffer` or are you asking how to do something like the code you show? What are you really asking?

Comment: No, it's not.  As the name indicates it's meant to select a *buffer*, not a file.